# Printing Custom Documents without displaying print preview page using Kotlin,Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, printing, android-print-framework

I am new to Android Development and I am creating an app that prints custom documents via printers but it displays the print preview page, after clicking the print button, hence I do not want to display the print preview page after the user enters the details and clicks submit, the document should directly get printed after clicking submit via the nearby wifi/bt printer after connecting to the respective printer.

I don't know what should I try to not display the print preview page, but I am able to print the custom document with the print preview page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.